# Google Sheets Script Editor Toast feature onFormSubmit Trigger not popping up

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, toast

The line of code

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Message", "Title");
```

gives a toast when executed. However, when placing it in a program with a form submit trigger, the toast does not pop up in the spreadsheet.

I have played around with this for hours and I believe this error is on Google's part. No errors occur when executing the code; the only problem is the toast not popping up.

Comment: Upon further investigation, a time trigger does not allow the toast to pop up either.

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to share the full script that performs the toast?
What you currently have works perfectly fine on my sheet so it must be something else.

Does the script have accurate permissions to the Spreadsheet?

It's not disappearing too quickly? By default it only stays up for a few seconds. You can set the toast to stay up until you close it by adding `-1` to your command:

```js
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Message", "Title", -1);
```

Comment: Matty, I do not have issues with the toast itself, but rather invoking the toast following a onFormSubmit trigger. The following code: `function onSubmit(e){
      Logger.log("Calling notify...");
      notify();
}

function notify(){
      Logger.log("Before toast");
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Message", "Title", -1);
      Logger.log("After toast");
}`
allows me to view all the logs, but the toast does not appear.